# MySQL decimal(24,16) produces strange results

Tags: mysql, database, magento, magento-1.7, decimal

I currently have a decimal(24,16) row in a mySQL database; but when I save data to it; it alters the value that I put in. As far I can currently see; the max of decimals I would need is 16.

An example:

- I put in: 5.96666666666667
- When I retrieve the data it returns 5.96666666666666995

Does this make sense? Do I need to find the answer in the way mySQL handles this; or should I look in my code (Magento - but it's been fully adapted to deal with more than 4 decimals, all I need to figure out is on how to make the database deal with it)

I know it's not a very specific question code wise, but I'm just trying to wrap my mind around this issue :-)

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Is that the output of the SQL Query or have you run that in PHP?

Comment: I suspect that your fixed-point value is being converted to a floating-point value somewhere in your application outside of MySQL.  If you depend upon the precise value, your application will have to use a data type that is sensitive to fixed point data (since Magento is coded in the very-loosely-typed PHP, you may have to treat your value as a string).

Comment: It is outputted by Magento. I will look into it tomorrow to see if I can find out where the conversion is happening and post back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get to the bottom of this. As suggested, there was nothing wrong with the data type of the MySQL row. I managed to trace it back to Magento (exact code location unknown).

When I make calculations on a similar setup; it all works fine, so it seems @eggyal's suggestion was correct.

So if you are looking for a way to get Magento to work with more than 4 decimals; I would advise you to stop trying ;)